# Multiple Independent parallel remote session RHEL7

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc, vncserver, vnc-viewer

I have x11vnc installed on host(RHEL7.2) which i run using x11vnc -forever command to have desktop session of this server on my remote(RHEL6.2) machine using vncviewer IPAddr:display command.

My requirement is to have **multiple independent remote session** of my host server from remote machine. **In current scenario when i take remote session from machine1 & machine2 both share the same desktop, whereas I want to have independent desktop so that multiple user can take remote of host without disturbing the work of other.**

x11vnc was used as it supports openGL graphics on remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with `x11vnc`, because it's tied to an existing X server. You would need an X server instance for each `x11vnc` instance.

Instead use something like `Xvnc`, which creates an X server with a "virtual" framebuffer.

Yes, you won't be able to support OpenGL like this, because there's only **one** graphics card with a GPU, and you cannot share that (easily) between X servers.

You can start a fixed number of `Xvnc` servers on system startup, or you can do more clever things like starting them from [xinetd/inetd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X11vnc#Running_from_xinetd) (yes, link is for ArchLinux; adapt for RHEL).

Comment: can it be achieved using alternatives of x11vnc available, if yes could you suggest something to address my requirement.

My requirement:-
VNC Server :- Supports OpenGL on remote machine.
VNC Server :- Supports multiple independent parallel remote session.
VNC Viewer :- Supports multiple independent parallel remote session.

Comment: `Xvnc` mentioned in the answer is an alternative. It's part of [tigervnc](https://tigervnc.org/doc/Xvnc.html).